How to Adjust parameters for training Tensor flow EfficientDet d0 model on a very small dataset
I am trying to extract details like invoice number, invoice date, total amount from multi layout pdf files. I have about 260 images in total for dataset after data argumentation. I am training EfficientDet d0 model and when I test the model on test images, however it identifies more than one bounding boxes for same target. Sometimes it is not identifying some of the targets at all. I might be making mistakes in adjusting the parameters for training. Is the parameters (learning rate, batch size, train steps, eval steps) that I have set correct?
optimizer {
momentum_optimizer: {
learning_rate: {
cosine_decay_learning_rate {
learning_rate_base: 2e-2
total_steps: 4000
warmup_learning_rate: 0.008
warmup_steps: 500
}
}

num_classes = 5
num_train_steps = 2500  
num_eval_steps = 500 
batch_size = 4  
checkpoint_type = 'detection'

